# Tem como recuperar arquivo usando o comando git voltando a data e horas do arquivo da versão anterior

Tags: git

Geralmente quando recuperamos  arquivo usando o comando git modifica a data a hora do arquivo do ramo principal ou específico, preciso que os arquivos do projeto sejam retornado como é feito o processo de restauração  sem afetar a alteração da data e hora do arquivo.

Comment: Não sou especialista no assunto mas acho que não vai conseguir com git o que quer. Essa funcionalidade que está procurando é uma característica de ferramentas de backup, como [Timeshift](https://wiki.debian.org/timeshift), e não de ferramentas de controle de versão como git.